# How to get the following ouput in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, scripting, devops

I am trying to compare two text files which has subnets and be able to get the outpu.
But I need the output in proper format.(line by line)
I also want to add a print statement as "Match in both the lists"

Currently I am getting the output as:

```
2.144.0.0/142.176.0.0/12root@vagrant-ubuntu
```

My expected output:

```
Match in both the lists
2.144.0.0/14
2.176.0.0/12
root@vagrant-ubuntu
```

Code

```
#Open the first file and read in each line as
#a value in a list called lines1. After reading
#each line, then strip off any extra whitespace
#or typeset characters.
with open('6output.txt') as f1:
    lines1 = f1.readlines()
    lines1 = [x.strip() for x in lines1]
f1.close()
#Open the second file and read in each line as
#a value in a list called lines2. After reading
#each line, then strip off any extra whitespace
#or typeset characters.
with open('7subnet.txt') as f2:
    lines2 = f2.readlines()
    lines2 = [x.strip() for x in lines2]
f2.close()
#Loop over each element in the two lists. If a
#match is found, then we write the value to the
#output file. If there is no match, output info.
test = 0
fileout = open('9output.txt', 'w')
for val1 in lines1:
    for val2 in lines2:
        if val1 == val2:
            fileout.write(val1)
test = 1
fileout.close()
if test == 0:
    print("No matches found!")
```

Comment: I've fixed (?) your indentation.  However, without the input files, it's not entirely clear what's happening here.

Comment: I think this is simply a matter of adding a line feed where you want it.  Change your output statement to `fileout.writeln(val1)`

Comment: I am getting this error

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "8filecomp.py", line 25, in <module>
    fileout.writeln(val1)
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'writeln'

Comment: Ah ... try `fileout.write(val1 + '\n')`.  My apologies -- wrong package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if this works. For writing in separate lines, you can use `"\n"`. And id you would want to put the phrase "Match in both the lists" only once, you will need to put an additional `if` statement.

```
test = 0
fileout = open('9output.txt', 'w')
for val1 in lines1:
    for val2 in lines2:
        if val1 == val2:
            if test == 0:
                fileout.write("Match in both the lists")
                fileout.write(val1+"\n")
                test = 1
            else:
                fileout.write(val1+"\n")
fileout.close()
if test == 0:
    print("No matches found!")
```

Comment: Rohit you made my day man. Thank you somuch. It worked as i expected. Awesome man cheers!

Comment: Why are you writing the header line for every match?  Why are you using 0/1 values instead of the natural Booleans?

Comment: The way you have edited, the header "Match in both the lists" will be printed even if there are no matches. That's why I have added an if condition, so that the header is printed only the first time a match is found.